# Including glibtop in linux CPU load

Tags: linux, glib

Here is my code to see CPU load in linux but I have some errors! I downloaded glibtop and put it in same directory as my program is but I have these errors!

```
    `#include "stdio.h"
     #include "glibtop.h"
     #include "glibtop/cpu.h"

     int main(){
     glibtop_init();
     glibtop_cpu cpu;
     glibtop_get_cpu (&cpu);
     printf("CPU TYPE INFORMATIONS \n\n"
     "Cpu Total : %ld \n"
     "Cpu User : %ld \n"
     "Cpu Nice : %ld \n"
     "Cpu Sys : %ld \n"
     "Cpu Idle : %ld \n"
     "Cpu Frequences : %ld \n",
     (unsigned long)cpu.total,
     (unsigned long)cpu.user,
     (unsigned long)cpu.nice,
     (unsigned long)cpu.sys,
     (unsigned long)cpu.idle,
     (unsigned long)cpu.frequency); 
     return 0;
     }`
```

my errors are:

```
cpuLoad.c:2:21: error: glibtop.h: No such file or directory
In file included from cpuLoad.c:3:
glibtop/cpu.h:25:21: error: glibtop.h: No such file or directory
glibtop/cpu.h:26:28: error: glibtop/global.h: No such file or directory
In file included from cpuLoad.c:3:
glibtop/cpu.h:59: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before      âtypedefâ
glibtop/cpu.h:63: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before âguint64â
glibtop/cpu.h:84: error: expected â)â before â*â token
glibtop/cpu.h:92: error: expected â)â before â*â token
glibtop/cpu.h:98: error: expected â)â before â*â token
glibtop/cpu.h:99: error: expected â)â before â*â token
cpuLoad.c:9: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âintâ
```

do you know what is the problem?I dontr know how should I tell linux the path of my .h files!

Comment: how did you install gtop?  if you are using fedora, use yum.  if you are on Debian or Ubuntu, use apt-get to install it.

Answer (score 1):

`gcc -I.` etc

[The manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) says:

> -I dir   Add the directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for header files.

Comment: gcc temp.c -I~Documents/libgtop-2.24.4 -o out.o I did this but it does not work!!

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried the same code above and it works like a charm.

```
$ gcc -Wall -g -Wextra main.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libgtop-2.0)
$ ./a.out
CPU TYPE INFORMATIONS

Cpu Total : 695672439
Cpu User : 4072158
Cpu Nice : 21564
Cpu Sys : 1523271
Cpu Idle : 687079036
Cpu Frequences : 100
```

It is on Debian Unstable amd64 with `libgtop2-dev` 2.28.4-3 and gcc 4.7.1.